# How to get data from a particular column in a gridview using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my application, I have a gridview from which I have to get data from a particular column. This data is to be stored in a datatable. How can I do that?

My code is not working properly.Here it is:

```
dim dt as datatable=ctype(Gridview1.coumns.items("Rate"),datatable)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use CellClick event of the gridview to fetch current column value and store it in session. then from session you can get the primary key.

```
private void gridview1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
       Session["primarykey"] = gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

//In the next page you have assign the session to variable primaykey by the following code.

```
string primarykey = Session["primarykey"].To
String();
```